# GWT debug eclipse unable to connect to chrome

Tags: javascript, eclipse, gwt

I am getting the following error when I try to debug my GWT app.  I am quite sure it is a problem with my code, I just don't know how to find where the problem is.

[image: Error when I bring up browser]

My immediate goal is to find and fix this particular error.  My ultimate goal is, obviously, to be able to debug my application in Eclipse.

Steps used:

1. Right click project in Eclipse, choose "GWT development mode with jetty"
2. Right click URL in GWT "Development Mode" tab, and choose "Open with SDJB Chrome JS Debugger"
3. Browser pops up, with error saying "Could not load application from super dev mode. Make sure your super dev mode server is running and url is properly configured, host: 127.0.0.1 port: 9876 module: wmsapp"
4. In eclipse, under browser window, I see the below error.  I don't see errors anyplace else in Eclipse.
5. In browser, with "Developer Tools" enabled, I do see a CORS error, refusing to load some script, and a failure to load the "favicon.ico".  I don't see how this could cause the below error message, but who knows.
6. I then try right clicking URL and "Open with Chrome", and get the same browser issues.  I never get the below error again, even on browser refreshes.
7. I then stopped the debugger, ran it again, and right clicked URL with "Open with Chrome", no error below, but same browser errors
8. I then right clicked and selected "Open with SDJB Chrome JS Debugger", got error below.

So it seems I only get the error below with "Open with SDJB Chrome JS Debugger" on my application.  When I do it on a demo application, it works fine, so it is definitely a problem with my application.  Any ideas?  Where can I look for the true problem in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick-and-dirty solution that is working for me.

I modified the jar of the SDBG plugin (installed from the Marketplace together with the GWT plugin) adding the classes of jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar and jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar. I put all classes from that 2 jars inside the com.github.sdbg.debug.core_1.0.10.201610081555.jar located in eclipse/plugins dir.
In this way I did not have to modify anything in my project that uses JDK 11 (no pom or JDK modification).

I suppose the modification impacts only the plugin itself for the activity of launching Chrome from eclipse, therefore my projects and environment should not be influenced.

Comment: I have the plugin installed for eclipse ee 2019-09 und 2021-09 ee but both do not show the .jar file in the eclipse/plugin dir (Windows). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

from a post on here [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javax/xml/bind/JAXBException](https://mkyong.com/java/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception/)

**A short history of JAXB on Java**

The Jakarta XML Binding (JAXB; formerly Java Architecture for XML Binding) is an XML binding framework to convert Java classes to and from XML.

1. The JAXB is part of Java 6, 7, and 8.
2. Java 9 deprecated the Java EE modules, including the JAXB packages
   javax.xml.*.
3. The JAXB APIs are still deprecated in Java 10.
4. Java 11 deleted the JAXB APIs javax.xml.* completely.
5. Oracle submitted the Java EE to Eclipse Foundation and repackaged it
   to jakarta.xml.* since version 3.0.

**Quick Solution**

Downgrade your Java used by eclipse to the version before Java 11.

**Long solution**

Check if the latest version is built on the base of Java 11, if yes then upgrade Your GWT, if not then hope someone will do that.

Comment: What means "Upgrade your GWT". I am using gwt2.10.0. This still shows this problem.